Lemma in Roth's Theorem for Primes
I am reading Ben Green's paper Roth's Theorem in the Primes and I don't follow the proof of Lemma 6.1. I am not sure where the fact there are no more than $n^{3/4}$ elements $x\in A_0$ with $x\leq n^{3/4}$ is used to deduce the inequality after that.

$\log x > \frac{3}{4}\log n$ if $x > n^{3/4}$

Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

@GHfromMO thank you for the suggestion and edit.

@mathworker21 how does that give the inequality?

Remove from $A_0$ all elements sharing a factor with $m$ or with $x \le n^{3/4}$, leaving a set $A'_0$. This is very few elements to throw away and you still have $|A'_0| \ge \frac{9}{10} \alpha_0 n/\log n$, say with any reasonable choice of the parameters (hopefully the ones in the paper actually work). Then use the inequality in mathworker21's comment for all $x \in A'_0$ and the claimed inequality should follow.

@BenGreen thank you for the explanation.
